# How to create a JSON file from another JSON file based on IF condition! Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file like this:

```
[
      {
            "id": "john",
            "title": "tech",
            "date": "2020/1/1",
            "shift": "DAYS"
      },
      {
            "id": "tom",
            "title": "tech",
            "date": "2021/5/5",
            "shift": "NIGHT"
      }
]
```

I need to re-create another JSON file based on this information. For example:

IF shift == NIGHT:

shiftHourStart = 22:00:00

shiftHourEnd = 06:00:00

So output should be like this:

```
[
      {
            "id": "john",
            "title": "tech",
            "shiftHourStart" = "22:00:00",
            "shiftHourEnd" = "06:00:00"
            "shift": "NIGHT"
      },
      {
            "id": "tom",
            "title": "tech",
            "date": "2021/5/5",
            "shiftHourStart" = "06:00:00",
            "shiftHourEnd" = "15:00:00",
            "shift": "DAY"          
      }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: Expected output doesn't match your description.

Comment: Read, process, write -- those are the steps and you can solve them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `dict.update`

```py
data = [
      {
            "id": "john",
            "title": "tech",
            "date": "2020/1/1",
            "shift": "DAYS"
      },
      {
            "id": "tom",
            "title": "tech",
            "date": "2021/5/5",
            "shift": "NIGHT"
      }
]

shift_mapping = {
    'DAYS': { # or DAY whatever you have
        "shiftHourStart": "22:00:00",
            "shiftHourEnd": "06:00:00"
    },
    'NIGHT':{
        "shiftHourStart": "06:00:00",
        "shiftHourEnd": "15:00:00",
    }
}

for each_shift in data:
    if 'shift' in each_shift:
        each_shift.update(shift_mapping[each_shift['shift']])
    else:
        print('Warning!! shift key does not exists!')
    
print(data)
```

```
[{'id': 'john',
  'title': 'tech',
  'date': '2020/1/1',
  'shift': 'DAYS',
  'shiftHourStart': '22:00:00',
  'shiftHourEnd': '06:00:00'},
 {'id': 'tom',
  'title': 'tech',
  'date': '2021/5/5',
  'shift': 'NIGHT',
  'shiftHourStart': '06:00:00',
  'shiftHourEnd': '15:00:00'}]
```

Comment: % python3 1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 47, in <module>
    make_json(inputFile, jsonFilePath)
  File "1.py", line 34, in make_json
    each_shift.update(shift_mapping[each_shift['shift']])
KeyError: 'shift'

Comment: that means not all of them have the key `shift`, what you want to do in that case? Drop that? Can you provide a larger input?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import json
json_text = """[
      {
            "id": "john",
            "title": "tech",
            "date": "2020/1/1",
            "shift": "DAYS"
      },
      {
            "id": "tom",
            "title": "tech",
            "date": "2021/5/5",
            "shift": "NIGHT"
      }
]
"""
n_dict = json.loads(json_text)
if n_dict[0]['shift'] == 'DAY':
    n_dict[0]["shiftHourStart"]="06:00:00"
    n_dict[0]["shiftHourEnd"] = "15:00:00"
else:
    n_dict[0]["shiftHourStart"]="22:00:00"
    n_dict[0]["shiftHourEnd"] = "06:00:00"
new_json = json.dumps(n_dict)
print(new_json)
```

**Edit for your case:**
If json file is `".\\file.json"` then,

```
import json
with open('.\\file.json') as f:
  json_text = json.load(f)
n_dict = json.loads(json_text)
if n_dict[0]['shift'] == 'DAY':
    n_dict[0]["shiftHourStart"]="06:00:00"
    n_dict[0]["shiftHourEnd"] = "15:00:00"
else:
    n_dict[0]["shiftHourStart"]="22:00:00"
    n_dict[0]["shiftHourEnd"] = "06:00:00"
with open('.\\new_file.json', 'w') as json_file:
  json.dump(n_dict, json_file)
```

Comment: I tested it and it runs without error, but nothing for output! Nothing changes or no file being created. I am loading the json file from a path, would it be the issue? like: jsonFilePath = r'myFile.json'